Re-rendering problem while doing infinite scrolling with redux
my redux actions:
export const RESTAURANT_SUCCESS = 'RESTAURANT_SUCCESS';
export const RESTAURANT_FAILURE = 'RESTAURANT_FAILURE';
export const GET_MORE_RESTAURANTS_SUCCESS = 'GET_MORE_RESTAURANTS_SUCCESS';

export const restaurantSuccess = (restaurants) => ({
type: RESTAURANT_SUCCESS,
payload: restaurants,
> });

export const restaurantsFailure = (error) => ({
type: RESTAURANT_FAILURE,
payload: error,
> });

export const getMoreRestaurants = (restaurants, page) => ({
type: GET_MORE_RESTAURANTS_SUCCESS,
payload: { restaurants, page },

redux reducer:
import { RESTAURANT_FAILURE, RESTAURANT_SUCCESS, GET_MORE_RESTAURANTS_SUCCESS } from './restaurantActions';

const initialState = {
  restaurants: [], 
  error: null,
  page: 1,
};

const restaurantReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RESTAURANT_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        restaurants: action.payload,
      };
    case RESTAURANT_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    case GET_MORE_RESTAURANTS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        restaurants: [...state.restaurants, ...action.payload.restaurants],
        page: action.payload.page,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default restaurantReducer;

jsx file:
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, Image, TextInput, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState, useEffect, memo } from 'react';
import Ionicons from '@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons';
import MaterialIcons from '@expo/vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import EvilIcons from '@expo/vector-icons/EvilIcons';
import AntDesign from '@expo/vector-icons/AntDesign';
import Categories from '../components/Categories';
import apiController from '../../axios/apiController';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getStars } from '../utils/ratingUtils';
import { GET_MORE_RESTAURANTS_SUCCESS } from '../../redux/restaurantActions';


const RestaurantItem = memo(({ name, address, image, review, onPress }) => (
  <View className="">
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      <View style={{ width: 335, height: 60, marginVertical: 10, position: 'relative', marginTop: 16 }}>
        <View style={{ width: 70, height: 60, borderRadius: 15, backgroundColor: '#d7d7d7', position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0 }}>
          <Image source={image} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', borderRadius: 15 }} resizeMode='cover' />
        </View>
        <View style={{ marginLeft: 85, marginTop: 0 }}>
          <Text style={{ color: '#3e3e3e', fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{name}</Text>
          <Text style={{ color: '#a3a3a3', fontSize: 11 }}>{address}</Text>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 2 }}>
            <View className="bg-primary" style={{ width: 30, height: 18, borderRadius: 7, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginRight: 5 }}>
              <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 11, fontWeight: 'normal' }}>{review}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
              {getStars(review)}
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
));

const ItemSeparator = memo(() => (
  <View style={{ height: 1, backgroundColor: '#d3d3d3', marginVertical: 10 }} />
));

const renderLoader = memo(() => (
  <View>
    <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="gray"/>
  </View>
));

const AllRestaurants = ({ navigation }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { restaurants, error, page } = useSelector(state => state.restaurant);
  const [loadingMore, setLoadingMore] = useState(false);
  const [isLastPage, setIsLastPage] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRestaurants = async () => {
      if (loadingMore || isLastPage) return;

      setLoadingMore(true);
      try {
        const response = await apiController.restaurant(page);

        
        if (response.length === 0) {
          setIsLastPage(true);
        } else {
          dispatch({ type: 'GET_MORE_RESTAURANTS_SUCCESS', payload: { restaurants: response, page: page + 1 } });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: 'RESTAURANT_FAILURE', payload: error.message });
        console.error('Error fetching restaurants:', error);
      }
      setLoadingMore(false);
    };

    fetchRestaurants();
  }, [dispatch, page, loadingMore, isLastPage]);

  const loadMoreItems = () => {
    if (!loadingMore && !isLastPage) {
      setLoadingMore(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#f1f0f3' }}>
      <View className="bg-white">
        <View className="flex-row items-center">
          <TouchableOpacity className="ml-2" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
            <Ionicons name="chevron-back-outline" size={22} color="gray" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', marginHorizontal: 2, marginVertical: 10, borderRadius: 35 }}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', width: '80%', height: 40, alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#f1f0f3', borderRadius: 20, paddingHorizontal: 10 }}>
              <EvilIcons name="search" size={30} color="gray" />
              <TextInput
                style={{ flex: 1, marginLeft: 10 }}
                placeholder="Yemek, mutfak veya restoran arayın"
                placeholderTextColor="gray"
              />
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', width: '15%', backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: 20, paddingHorizontal: 10 }}>
              <AntDesign name="filter" size={20} color="red" />
              <Text style={{ color: '#ff5656', fontSize: 10 }}>Filtrele</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View className="mt-4">
          <Categories />
        </View>
      </View>
      <FlatList
        data={restaurants}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <RestaurantItem name={item.name} address={item.address.shortAddress} review={item.rating} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Restaurant Detail', { place: item })} />}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 10 }}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparator}
        initialNumToRender={15}
        ListFooterComponent={renderLoader}
        onEndReached={loadMoreItems}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default AllRestaurants;

my store:
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { combineReducers} from 'redux';
import addressReducer from './addressReducer';
import authReducer from './authReducer';
import restaurantReducer from './restaurantReducer';
import locationReducer from './locationReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    address: addressReducer,
    auth: authReducer,
    restaurant: restaurantReducer,
    location: locationReducer
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      immutableCheck: false,  
      serializableCheck: false, 
    }),
});

export default store;


import apiYakala from "./apiYakala";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const registerController = async (body) =\> {
try {
const response = await apiYakala.post('/api/users', body);
const { token } = response;
await AsyncStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token);
return response;
} catch (error) {
console.error('Registration Error:', error.response?.data || error.message);
throw new Error("Hata kodu: " + error.response?.status);
}
}

const loginController = async (body) =\> {
const response = await apiYakala.post('/api/users/login', body);

    const { token } = response;
    
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token);
    
    return response;

}

const restaurantController = async(page=1) =\> {
return await apiYakala.get(`/api/places?page=${page}`);
}

export default {
register: registerController,
login: loginController,
restaurant: restaurantController
};


import axios from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const api = axios.create({
baseURL: "https://api.yaka.la",
timeout: 1000,
responseType: 'json',
withCredentials: true,
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Accept' : 'application/json'
}
});

api.interceptors.request.use(
async (config) =\> {
const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('jwtToken');
if (token) {
config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
}
return config;
},
(error) =\> {
return Promise.reject(error);
}
);

export default {
post: async (url, body, additionalHeaders = {}) =\> {
try {
const response = await api.post(url, body, {
headers: { ...additionalHeaders }
});
return response.data;
} catch (error) {
console.error(error.response.data);
throw new Error("Hata kodu: " + error.response?.status);
}
},
get: async (url, additionalHeaders = {}) =\> {
try {
const response = await api.get(url, {
headers: { ...additionalHeaders }
});
return response.data;
} catch (error) {
console.error(error.response.data);
throw new Error("Hata kodu: " + error.response?.status);
}
},
patch: async (url, body, additionalHeaders = {}) =\> {
try {
const response = await api.patch(url, body, {
headers: { ...additionalHeaders }
});
return response.data;
} catch (error) {
console.error(error.response.data);
throw new Error("Hata kodu: " + error.response?.status);
}
}
};


I want to add an infinite scrolling to show all restaurants to user when user scrolling up.But when scrolling up, it always re-rendering same restaurants with new ones. İ just want to see the new ones. I couldn't solve this problem if anyone knows how to deal with this issue please help me.

Help me understand. loadMoreItems sets loadingMore to true, which triggers the use effect, which bails early because loadingMore is true. Are you seeing a second page of items get fetched?

yes items get fetched but the problem is items get fetched multiple times.

Isnt page different on each response, so that triggers the effect, which fetches more?

yes i get 15 items for each page, and here: const restaurantController = async(page=1) => { return await apiYakala.get(/api/places?page=${page}); } i fetch datas page by page. I guess i make mistake in redux when i do payload. I just want to do that when i do infinite scrolling, items of page one shown on the screen then user scrolling items of page two adding the previous one.

So it makes sense why it’s fetching them all at once
